# Fragment Life cycle issue

Tags: android, fragment

I have implemented a Fragment and override its lifecycle callbackas as following:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        dactivity = getActivity();
        dactivity.bindService(new Intent(dactivity,EventosDatabaseService.class), this, 0);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dactivity.unbindService(this);
    }
```

It is documented that onActivityCreated call must heppen prior to onDestroy, then how come i get NullPointerException thrown because dactivity is null on onDestroy? what should i do to avoid it while making sure the binding wont produce a leak?

BTW, the RetainInstance of this fragment is false if that metters

Comment: Do your unbinding before calling the super.onDestroy()

Comment: ideally you should bind in onResume and unbind on onPause. have you used onPause and other methods? Can you post the whole Fragment code here. Just by looking at the parts you have pasted, everything looks fine.

Comment: @DroidBender still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bind your service in `Fragment.onResume` with registering broadcast listeners if available, and use `Fragment.onPause` to unbind service and unregister listeners

Answer (score 0):

I wish the image i posted could offer better understanding to figure out how `fragments` work.
[image]